# HTTP Post converts € to ? symbol

Tags: php, android, http

My Android app communicates via HTTP Post with a PHP server.
I add to the HTTP request following parameter:

```
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", message));
```

message is a String and contains the symbol €

On the server PHP is running and gets the request. 
Unfortunatelly the € symbol is automatically converted to ? symbol.
All other symbols are working like "ä, ü, $, ß

On Android I have set no encoding:

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server.com/test.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
```

On the PHP site I have also nothing specified.
Here the code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("blablaost.com", "blabla", "blabla") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("asfd") or die(mysql_error());
$mysqldate = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$language = (int) $_REQUEST['language'];

mysql_query("blabla ... .$_REQUEST['text']. ") 
or die(mysql_error());  

mysql_close();

?>
```

$_REQUEST['text'] contains the € and it gives me a ?

Comment: Can you check the encoding both sides are sending/expecting?

Comment: Any luck messing around with urldecode() and rawurldecode() on the php side?
How are you checking the result?

Comment: it seems the output/input encoding of PHP server is ISO-8859-1. I check it by writing it in mySQL DB. But this is not the fault! I am not sure what I should do with urldecode()..

Comment: urldecode() and rawurldecode() are not the right way. I am sending the value via HTTP post. It is not appended in the URL

Comment: Url encoding is required when POSTing url encoded data since you're declaring the data to be url encoded.

Comment: Yup, I'd still try those two first.
And then look at this: Windows 1252 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) has a euro sign where ISO-8859-1 interfering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) has control characters, any windows-1252 encoding along the way?

Comment: ok. I post my server code above. Can you tell me what I have to do? there do I have to use this urldecode() function?

Comment: I have tried it with rawurldecode($_REQUEST['text']) and urldecode($_REQUEST['text']), but still getting a ? instead of €

Comment: Have you verified the HTTP headers declare the correct content encoding?

Comment: Can you tell me how I should do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second construction parameter of UrlEncodedFormEntity is the transmit encoding. Replace with:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
```

Also, make sure that the Web page that displays the value reports a charset to the browser and conforms to that charset. To report the charset to the browser, use either

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8", true);
```

in PHP, or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
```

element under HTML's `<head>`. The former trumps the latter, if both are provided.

The actual encoding that the PHP file has (i. e. the encoding of non-ASCII characters in it) has to match the one PHP file claims as its Content-Type. Depending on your PHP editor, there may be different ways to set the encoding of the file. In Visual Studio, for example, there's a "Save with encoding" command.

EDIT re: unrelated issue:

To remove PHP magic quotes, I use the following function:

```
function deq($s) //Stands for "dequote"
{
    if($s == null)
        return null;
    return
        get_magic_quotes_gpc() ?
        stripslashes($s) : $s;
}
```

And then instead of $_POST["xxx"], I use deq($_POST["xxx"]) where appropriate. Since the server settings may change (and the server itself might change if you migrate), the dequote function must take the current value of the setting into account.

Comment: ok now I get for € symbol something like -â .. I think I have to set the encoding also in the php file?

Comment: The encoding that the PHP file has (i. e. the encoding of non-ASCII characters in it) has to match the one PHP file claims as Content-Type. Depending on your PHP editor, there may be different ways; in Visual Studio, for example, there's a "Save with encoding" command.

Comment: I have put the encoding of the php file to utf-8 lf, but still get problem with this line: if(md5(utf8_encode($_REQUEST['text']."test")) == $_REQUEST['hash'])   if the text contains a €, I am evaluates to false

Comment: I have remove utf8_encode() and now it works for all characters beside the symbols \ " and '

Comment: The issue with quotes is probably caused by the PHP's "magic quotes" feature. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: That seems to be the problem. How can I disable it? It is not my server.

Comment: See the edit. Since the server settings may change (and the server itself might change), your "dequote" funcion must take the current value of the setting into account.

Comment: Thx, I will test it. At the moment I am taking a bath with my tablet :)